# Attempting to Determine Progress Between 3 Columns Which May Contain Blank Values

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am a teacher trying to track progress of my students' grades over 3 assessments using Excel. Unfortunately, absences can cause blank values to occur within the columns. I would do (ex. P2, Q2, R2 contain data and S2 being the progress made between P2 and R2) =R2-P2, which would work, but it would not work if a student was absent and did not have a value within P2 or R2. Ideally, I would like to keep the formula consistent throughout the entire progress column.

As shown in the example, columns P, Q, R are the assessments and S is the overall progress. For Column S, I would like to show the overall growth that was made between these assessments. However, the issue is that sometimes, students are not able to be in attendance for these assessments, so the cell will be blank. The formula mentioned by Spectral Instance worked when P and R only had values, but did not work when just P or just R were missing. The last two rows show where the formula did not work correctly. In those instances, I would like to then only show progress with the assessments did take. Is there a formula that will work universally no matter which of the 3 columns are missing data?

This is shown in the example in the photo that is attached.

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y31D.png)

Can someone please provide insight as to how I can correctly track progress?

Comment: `=IF(A2*C2=0,0,C2-A2)`

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried this out with one data set that did not have a C column value. Seems it did not work on my end. If a student was absent for the assessment from the C column, is there a way to keep the formula you provided but use B column instead in that one instance (without it changing the existing formula in other rows)?

Comment: The formula I provided reproduced the column D values in your screenshot - rather than having several comments, please edit your question to include a screenshot illustrating all of the different possibilities for an absence, and how the progress should look in each such case.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @SpectralInstance I put it in below as my response.  I apologize if my original question was unclear or I did not communicate it accurately. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @player0 It is located below. Thank you for your interest in assisting me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have headers in Row 1, that data begins in Row 2, and that the only data down the columns is score data — delete everything in Col D (including the header). Then place the following formula in D1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Progress";IF(MMULT(IF(A2:C>0,1,0),{1;1;1})<2,,REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"~"&B2:B&"~"&C2:C,"(\d+)~*$")-REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"~"&B2:B&"~"&C2:C,"^~*(\d+)"))})`

This one formula will return the header (which you can change as you like within the formula itself) and all results for all rows where there are at least two entries. If there are fewer than two entries, null will be returned. You will *not* drag this formula down.

Understand that this is an array formula that will "own" *all* of Col D. So you will not be able to type anything into Col D manually without "breaking the array" (which will result in an error in cell D1 and all rows of formulaic data being blank).

As to how the formula works, `MMULT` (as used here) just counts valid values row-by-row. `IF` uses that count to determine if there are at least two values.

The two commas together is actually "comma-null" (meaning return null if the count of values is less than 2 in any row).

Otherwise, `REGEXEXTRACT` will act on a concatenation of all cell values with a tilde `~` separating them. The last value present will be taken from which the first value will be subtracted.

I cannot fully explain `MMULT` nor REGEX2 expressions in this post, but I trust the gist is clear.

Comment: I am probably not adding it correctly, as I am getting the "There's a problem with this formula" message. I removed the header and data.

Comment: Please provide a link to the sample spreadsheet. That will be the most efficient means of testing an answer against your actual data, international locale, etc. My formula works with my version of your data, but there is no way for me to test a formula against your data unless you share a link.

Comment: In case it is not obvious to you, I wrote my formula as if your scores were in Cols A, B and C and began in Row 2, with headers in Row 1 (I could only assume this, because you didn't show any row or column information in your image.) In your new image, you show that score data is in P, Q and R (no row is shown), so you need to modify my formula to reflect those columns.

Comment: Since there is sensitive information regarding the students in the original document, I copied and pasted some data sets into a Google Sheets file. Hopefully this is sufficient. Thank you! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-4y7fOKZIo6BHvN7c5qUXPfWvnuCdenMzi2LXJ4ivtM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Now that I can get into the sheet, I added a duplicate sheet named "Erik Help." In that sheet, I delete what you had in Col H, pasted my exact formula from my post here into A1, and then just changed every `A`, `B` and `C` in my formula to `E`, `F` and `G` respectively (which is where your data is). And it works as expected, as you will see in the sheet. Where a row is blank or where there is no progress (i.e., there is only 1 score currently), the result is left blank.

Comment: If the formula I provided is working as expected, please take a moment to mark the answer post as "Best Answer." This alerts the contributor community that the post no longer requires review, and it helps future site visitors like yourself quickly find answers to their own inquiries.

Answer (score 0):

[image: NEW EXAMPLE]

As shown in the example, columns P, Q, R are the assessments and S is the overall progress. For Column S, I would like to show the overall growth that was made between these assessments. However, the issue is that sometimes, students are not able to be in attendance for these assessments, so the cell will be blank. The formula mentioned by Spectral Instance worked when P and R only had values, but did not work when just P or just R were missing. The last two rows show where the formula did not work correctly. In those instances, I would like to then only show progress with the assessments did take. Is there a formula that will work universally no matter which of the 3 columns are missing data?

Once again, thank you all for your insight and feedback. I apologize if this is a small fix that I am maybe missing.

Comment: `=IF(P2=0,R2-Q2,IF(R2=0,Q2-P2,R2-P2))`

Comment: This worked for the majority of the rows, except for if the student took the first test, but missed the second and third. For example, Column P, 211 score; Column Q and R, BLANK. The formula results in a -211. The same would apply if P and R were missing. If possible, is there a way for the formula to show a 0 in that instance, since they did not show progress or regression being that it was their only assessment? I'm not sure if adding anything extra to that existing formula will create a "too many arguments" message.

Comment: That is why I asked you for a " a screenshot illustrating all of the different possibilities for an absence, and how the progress should look in each such case", a simple enough request I think, but one which remains unanswered

Comment: @SpectralInstance My apologies. I was on break at work and sent to you quickly without looking it over. I replied with another answer in "EXAMPLE 3." Thank you for your assistance. I truly appreciate it.